# Multidimensional array_values only on integer keys

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to make code to organize an array. I have this code:

```
$arr =  array(0=>array('key 1'=>'value 1', 'key 2'=>'value 2', 'key 3'=> array('2'=>'more values 1', '5'=>'more values 2', 7=>'more values 3')),
              2=>array(0=>'value 1', 2=>'value 2', 4=> array('key 2'=>'more values 1', 'key 5'=>'more values 2', 'key 7'=>'more values 3')));

echo print_r($arr);
```

Yields:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [key 1] => value 1
            [key 2] => value 2
            [key 3] => Array
                (
                    [2] => more values 1
                    [5] => more values 2
                    [7] => more values 3
                )
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => value 1
            [2] => value 2
            [4] => Array
                (
                    [key 2] => more values 1
                    [key 5] => more values 2
                    [key 7] => more values 3
                )
        )
)
```

I wanted the keys to integers could be renamed with `array_values()`.  The array needs output like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [key 1] => value 1
            [key 2] => value 2
            [key 3] => Array
                (
                    [0] => more values 1
                    [1] => more values 2
                    [2] => more values 3
                )
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => value 1
            [1] => value 2
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [key 2] => more values 1
                    [key 5] => more values 2
                    [key 7] => more values 3
                )
        )
)
```

But unfortunately I could not make a code that work.

Comment: That is an interesting problem, but why?  It is just a list, why does the numeric key matter?

Comment: imo, If you want to process a PHP array and you don't know the keys - then just use an iterator? i,e, `foreach ($inputArray as $key => $value) { ...`. If you meet another array then just `recurse` with the new array. Note: you will discover all the entries and don't need to know anything about the ''array keys'. It tells you what the array key is.

Comment: @AbraCadaver: I'm new to PHP and was creating a script that could use in a for statement (with integers) and preserve the non-integer index. I promise to study and improve my codes ever again. One more time, thanks for your great help.

Comment: @RyanVincent : Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be very rare that you would need to do this as you can access the array elements without incrementing keys, say with `foreach()`.  But here is a recursive function:

```
function array_reindex_recursive(&$array) {
    if(is_int(key($array))) {
        $array = array_values($array);
    }
    foreach($array as $key => &$val) {
        if(is_array($val)) {
            array_reindex_recursive($val);
        }
    }
}    

array_reindex_recursive($arr);
```

- Check the first key in the array to see if it is integer (this could be a problem if other keys are not integer)
- If so run `array_values()` to reindex
- Loop through the values and if one is an array call the function recursively

If you want to make sure that ALL keys are integer then replace the first `if` with something like this:

```
if(count(array_filter(array_keys($array), 'is_int')) == count($array)) {
    $array = array_values($array);
}
```

- Filter out all non-integer keys and compare with the length of the original array
- If the same length then all keys were integer, run `array_values()` to reindex

Comment: Wow! Works like a charm. Thank you VERY much!